# File Upload with jquery AJAX and FormData

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, file-upload, knockout.js

I am trying to upload a file from a form to a PHP Server via JQuerys AJAX method and the FormData method.

I use knockoutJS to trigger the submit action after pressing the upload button.

The HTML Form:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" data-bind="submit: addNewFile">
                        <fieldset>
                            <legend>Add File</legend>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="inputFile" class="col-lg-2 control-label">File</label>
                                    <input type="file" id="inputFile" name="inputFile">
                            </div>       
                            <div class="form-group">
                                    <button class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                            </div>

                        </fieldset>
                        </form>
```

The triggered javascript-code:

```
self.addNewFile = function (content){
    var formData = new FormData(content[1].files[0]);

    $.ajax({
        url: '../api/addFile',
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        contenType: false,
        processData: false})
}
```

The formData variable looks like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZ06z.png

And the http request looks like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Whfe.png

There is no file that is transfered to the server. The content-type is set to application/x-www-form-urlencoded but it should be multipart/form-data.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FormData constructor takes a HTMLFormElement, i.e. a form not a file, to add an individual file you have to use the [`append`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData#Methods) method

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file',content[1].files[0]);
```

also you spelt `contenType` incorrectly it should be `contentType`, notice the 2 Ts together

Comment: thank you, there seems to be an attempt to upload the file now, because the size of the request increased. The content-type is still application/x-www-form-urlencoded.
http://i.imgur.com/PqHSGqh.png 
But I am still not able to retreave the file on my Zend Framework 2 Server using `$file = $this->params()->fromFiles();`.